# Edit text gave late response to key press

Tags: android, android-edittext, onkeypress

[image]

I am setting above image as a background to a edit text. **Problem is edit text give late response to key press**. Below is my xml edit text declaration

```
  <com.spsoft.batterycheck.controls.RobotaBoldEditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_batteryname"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/box"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLength="32"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_digital_size" />
```

Comment: Are you using custom edittext...?

Comment: Yes...
Custom edit text with different font

Answer (score 0):

Set this property to your editText

android:focusable="true"